# VBA Code to Copy Cells with Color to different cells in same sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue which is to copy cells that contain a color and some value in it to a range. The issue with the below code is that it copy pastes the entire range and not the ones that are in red color.

```
Sub testing()

Dim Myrange As Range
Dim Mycell As Range
Dim Target As Range

Set Myrange = Sheet1.Range("A3:A15")
Set Target = Sheet1.Range("B3:B15")

For Each Mycell In Myrange
    If Mycell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
       Mycell.Copy Target
    End If
Next Mycell

End Sub
```

My expected result is to copy paste cells that contain only red color in the target range. (If A3 cell is red color I want B3 cell to be red color as well. But what I dont want is the entire range of the target cells to turn red)

Comment: `Mycell.Copy mycell.offset(,1)`

Comment: `Mycell.Copy Sheet1.Range("B" & Mycell.row)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `target` range is not needed, if you are planning to offset by 1:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim myCell As Range

    Set myRange = Worksheets(1).Range("A3:A15")

    For Each myCell In myRange
        If myCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
           myCell.Copy myCell.Offset(0, 1)
        End If
    Next myCell

End Sub
```

Or if you need to use the `target` for whatever reason, looping by index would be ok in this case, as the cells are in 1 row:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim myCell As Range

    Set myRange = Worksheets(1).Range("A3:A15")
    Set target = myRange.Offset(columnoffset:=1)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To myRange.Cells.Count
        If myRange.Cells(i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
            myRange.Cells(i).Copy target.Cells(i)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```